# How to simple animate a number to a certain percent with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, percentage

I don't want the progress bar, I just want to animate the number to a certain percentage

```
$('#animate_percent').click(function() {
//How the h#$%^ is this *%&&^*
}); 


<!--Animate 20% to 50%-->
<span class="tabs_percent">20%</span>
```

Comment: add css js and work done on http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval):

```
var counter;

$('#animate_percent').on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var $percent = $('.tabs_percent'),
        curr = parseInt($percent.text()),
        to = 50;

    counter = window.setInterval(function() {  
        if(curr <= to)
        {
            $percent.text((curr++)+'%');
        }
        else
        {
            window.clearInterval(counter);
        }
    }, 20);    
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sw81Lw54/1/)

Comment: Yeah. Is it easier this way? What about .animate()?

Comment: @diEcho Where did the OP ask for a solution that uses jQuery's `animate()` function? Also, please show me how you can use `animate()` to animate the `innerHTML` of an element...

Comment: @AlbertDrew since you want to animate the actual content of the `<span>`, rather than a CSS property or such, you can't use `animate()` - jQuery's function does not allow the animation of `innerHTML`.